# How to return an average grade with people's names and grades?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def average_grade(L):
    '''(list of list) -> list
    L is a list of lists of strings. The first item in each
    sublist is a student name and the rest of the strings in the 
    sublist are grade values (numeric). Return a 
    new list of lists where each sublist has length 2 of
    the form [student_name (str), average grade (float)]
    >>> average_grade([['Bob', 56, 80, 72, 90], ['Alice', 60, 88, 44, 70], ['Joe', 44, 100, 80, 60, 50]])
    [['Bob', 74.5], ['Alice', 65.5], ['Joe', 66.8]]
    '''
    new_list = [[]]
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if type(item) == type('a'):
            new_list.append(L)
            if type(item) == type(50):
                new_list.append(sum(L)/len(L))
    return new_list
```

I have this, and it doesn't work, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Where do you declare the `item` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
def average_grade(lst):
    """ Return students' names and their average grades. """

    # This whole block can be replaced with this one-liner:
    # return [[sub[0], sum(sub[1:]) / len(sub[1:])] for sub in lst]

    averages = []

    for sublist in lst:
        student = sublist[0]
        grades = sublist[1:]
        average = sum(grades) / len(grades)
        averages.append([student, average])

    return averages

>>> average_grade([['Bob', 56, 80, 72, 90], ['Alice', 60, 88, 44, 70], ['Joe', 44, 100, 80, 60, 50]])
[['Bob', 74.5], ['Alice', 65.5], ['Joe', 66.8]]
```

Comment: Just curious, how would we do it if the numbers were strs as well?

Comment: @dg123, good question. immediately after `grades` variable in the `for` loop, insert `grades = list(map(int, grades))`

Comment: @dg123, see https://repl.it/MSZ2/0

Comment: @dg123, you can also replace the `grades` variable with `grades = list(map(int, sublist[1:]))`

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the way lists work. You need to create a temp list each time you loop from L and add this temp list inside the outer list.
Here is an implementation for your code.

```
def average_grade(L):
    '''(list of list) -> list
    L is a list of lists of strings. The first item in each
    sublist is a student name and the rest of the strings in the 
    sublist are grade values (numeric). Return a 
    new list of lists where each sublist has length 2 of
    the form [student_name (str), average grade (float)]
    >>> average_grade([['Bob', 56, 80, 72, 90], ['Alice', 60, 88, 44, 70], ['Joe', 44, 100, 80, 60, 50]])
    [['Bob', 74.5], ['Alice', 65.5], ['Joe', 66.8]]
    '''
    # Output list.
    new_list = []
    number_of_subjects = float(len(L[0][1:]))
    for lis in L:
        name = lis[0]
        # Using / instead of // to avoid generating integer results
        average = float(sum(lis[1:])) / number_of_subjects
        new_list.append([name, average])
    return new_list
```

Comment: Why did you do len(L[0]) - 1?

Comment: The frequency of numbers is one less than than whole list. I could also have used len(L[1:]). I avoided recalculating the sum inside of loop again and again.

Comment: Edited the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your example input is not a list of list of strings. Each sublist contains one string and the rest are numeric. Your code doesn't work for a large number of reasons, including `item` not being defined, appending `new_list` with the entire input of the function, and proceeding to treat `L` as if it were a sublist, not the whole list. If this is important for you to understand, I suggest you go back and evaluate what each line of your code does; for example, print several variables after each line. At any rate:

```
def average_grade(L):
    new_list = []
    for l in L:
        name = l[0]
        grades = [float(val) for val in l[1:]] # Now works when grades are strings or numerics
        average = sum(grades)/len(grades)
        new_list.append([name, average])
    return new_list
```

Comment: This looks like a  good way to do it as well, thanks

Comment: Just curious, how would we do this if the numbers were strs as well?

Comment: You can cast each `string` value as a `float`, for example using list comprehension. I edited my answer, which now works if the input grades are strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python3.3+. You could also change this to a list comprehension.

```
def average_grade(grade_book):
    return [
        [name, sum(grades)/len(grades)]
        for name, *grades in grade_book
    ]
```